# JPA persistence unit into file?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, persistence.xml, persistence-unit

I use JPA to persist my data to a MySQL database and it all works pretty fine. Now I need to store a couple of configurations on the system the program is executed from.

In past I would have created a settings.ini or a settings.xml file and pretty much stored my stuff into it manually. But now I am asking myself whether it is possible to create a second persistence unit in the persistence.xml which would enable me to store my data into an xml-file.

Is that possible? Can I create a persistence unit that puts my data in an xml file instead of a database?

Comment: never heard of anything like this, but maybe you can do it using something like this http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_xml_jdbc.htm

Comment: if it works, don't forget to tell us :-)

Comment: I think this matter may be better solved with XPath and XQuery.

Comment: @MelaukiMawi Thanks for the tip! Will try myself with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MelaukiMawi! The right way would be to create and manage an XML file with XPath and XQuery.